# Reusable component implementing ControlValueAccessor fires onChange when changing the value programmatically

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm doing a mobile app using **Ionic** and **Angular** with **Reactive Forms**.

I have a reusable component to enter a phone number, this component implements the `ControlValueAccessor` interface. In addition, this component has a button below to choose a phone number from your contact list, when I set the value programmatically, **the onChange event is fired twice**.

**Reusable component**

```
export class PhoneNumberFormControl implements ControlValueAccessor {

  value: string;

  /**
   * With this I change the value programmatically.
   */
  set newValue(newValue: T) {
    if (newValue !== this.value) {
      this.value = newValue;
      this.onChange(newValue); // <= Notify the parent form
    }
  }

  onChange = (newValue: T) => {};
  onTouched = () => {};

  constructor(
    @Optional() @Self() public ngControl: NgControl
  ) {
    if (ngControl != null) {
      ngControl.valueAccessor = this;
    }
  }

  writeValue(value: T): void {
    if (value !== this.value) {
      this.value = value;
    }
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
  }

  async openModal() {
    // Logic to open a modal
    string phoneNumber = '7871234567';

    if (phoneNumber) {
      // 1. Changing the value programmatically, onChange is called, see setter above
      this.newValue = phoneNumber;
      // 2. Let the parent know that the input was touched because you have used the modal. This is wrong?
      this.onTouched();
    }
  }

}
```

**Template**

```
<ion-input [(ngModel)]="value"
           (ionBlur)="onTouched()"
           (ionChange)="onChange($event.target.value)">
</ion-input>

<ion-button (click)="openModal()">
  Select from contacts
</ion-button>
```

**Problem:**

The `ion-input` has the `ionChange` event because you can write manually a phone number. Good so far.

If you open the modal to choose a phone number, the ionChange is called to let the parent know of this change, but also, the `ionChange` of the `ion-input` is called because it's a change. Here is where I have the event being called twice.

**Example**

*The template part is omitted because is not important.*

```
export class ExamplePage implements OnInit {

      form: FormGroup;
    
      constructor(
        private fb: FormBuilder
      ) {
      }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.form = this.fb.group({
          phoneNumber: [null, Validators.required]
        });
        this.form.get('phoneNumber').valueChanges.subscribe(() => this.doLogic());
      }
    
      // This is being called twice when choosing a phone number from the modal
      doLogic() {
        console.log('I was called');
      }
    
    }
```

I have tried a few things but the result is the same.

My goal is to know how to implement this correctly to notify the parent just once.

Answer (score 0):

After some time debugging the issue, I have found that I forgot an important thing of inputs and events on changes.

I had this:

```
async openModal() {
  string phoneNumber = '7871234567';

  if (phoneNumber) {
    this.newValue = phoneNumber;
    this.onTouched();
  }
}
```

The setter `this.newValue = phoneNumber` is calling the `onChange()`, letting know the parent of the change, but after this, the `ion-input` also have the `(ionChange)="onChange($event.target.value)` event, which notifies again the parent.

The fix is just doing this:

```
async openModal() {
   string phoneNumber = '7871234567';
    
   if (phoneNumber) {
      this.value = phoneNumber;
   }
}
```

That sets a new value for the `ion-input`, which notifies the parent thanks to its `ionChange()` event. This way, the parent is notified just once.

I don't know if this is the recommended way, but it works.